# Ambiguous Laravel version

Tags: laravel

I am going to start working on existing Laravel project and I checked Laravel version using 2 ways:

1. I run `php artisan --version` and `Laravel Installer 4.2.10` got printed.
2. I checked `composer.json` file and there is `laravel/framework": "^8.0`.

Which one is real one? Thank you in advance.

PS: This question is not about how to. It is about why 2 different method return 2 different answer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, the `Laravel Installer` is the composer laravel installer which allows devs to run

`laravel new blog`

instead of

`composer create-project laravel/laravel:^8.0 blog`

`Laravel Framework` is the one that will advise what version of laravel you are running

Answer (score 0):

Search in composer.lock `"name": "laravel/framework",` for see current installed version
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- using `php artisan --version` to check via CLI.
- `{{ app()->version() }}` to print version in blade template.